# SQL Alternative for FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, adodb

For some reason my query :

```
SELECT 
    MP_SQLQRY_ProjectArchive.ProjectShort, 
    MP_SQLQRY_ProjectArchive.ProjectName ,
    MP_SQLQRY_ProjectArchive.ProjectManagerName ,
    ProjectOwnerName,
    ProjStateName,
    ProjectKategoryShort,
    ProjectTypeShort,
    MP_SQLQRY_ProjectArchive.ProjectPriority,
    DepartmentShort,
    ProjectArchivedDate,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),ERPAccountCodes.ERPAccountCodes) As ERPAccountCodes
FROM 
    MP_SQLQRY_ProjectArchive
INNER JOIN 
    SQLQRY_VALID_PROJECT_ORDER_INFO ON MP_SQLQRY_ProjectArchive.ProjectID = SQLQRY_VALID_PROJECT_ORDER_INFO.ProjectID
INNER JOIN 
    COM_tbl_MAD_Project ON MP_SQLQRY_ProjectArchive.ProjectID = COM_tbl_MAD_Project.ProjectID
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         ProjectID, 
         CONVERT(Nvarchar(max), STUFF((SELECT ';' + [SAPNumber] AS [data()]
                                       FROM [COM_tbl_MAD_ProjectERPAccountCode] t2
                                       WHERE t2.[ProjectID] = t1.[ProjectID]
                                       ORDER BY [SAPNumber]
                                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) AS ERPAccountCodes
     FROM  
         [COM_tbl_MAD_ProjectERPAccountCode] t1
     GROUP BY 
         [ProjectID], [SAPNumber]) AS ERPAccountCodes ON ERPAccountCodes.ProjectID = COM_tbl_MAD_Project.ProjectID
```

will not return the values for the ERPAccountCodes column. In SQL Server, it works fine and I get my values, which are seperated with a `;` as I want.

But when I run it as extern connection with ADODB in access this single column is empty.

I suppose it is a problem with access or ADODB but I have no clue what to do about it

Is there an alternative to `FOR XML PATH` or is there a different way to do it?

For clarification, the values return some blank values. Not NULL, just these weird blank symbols when i debugged in VBA in access, altough I tried converting it into a NVarchar which theoretically should work just fine.

Left is an Excel created from the MS Access SQL call. Right is from SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried creating stored procedure in SQL Server, and calling it from Access instead of plain query?

Comment: No but I do need the information gathered from the statement in access, and therefore I would still not work. I already use an extern connection but the error happens somewhere while getting it into access

Comment: Use `STRING_AGG` instead (if you're on a more recently version)?

Comment: We don't know enough of your code behind all this... It might be, that your application uses a CSV file between access and excel which uses the semicolon as delimiter. This might mix something up...

Comment: Does not depend on the character used to seperate. Does also not work with "," or "-" or something else

Comment: Gonna give String_agg a shot

Comment: try CONVERT(Nvarchar(4000), STUFF...) instead of nvarchar(max)

Comment: I am using `FOR XML PATH` in several SQL views which are than linked to Access and never had such problems. Try it.